# Painter's partition using Dynamic Programming

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming, recurrence

PROBLEM STATEMENT:

You have to paint N boards of length {A0, A1, A2 … AN-1}. There are K painters available and you are also given how much time a painter takes to paint 1 unit of board. You have to get this job done as soon as possible under the constraints that any painter will only paint continuous sections of board, say board {2, 3, 4} or only board {1} or nothing but not board {2, 4, 5}.

How to solve this problem using dynamic programming.One approximation to this problem is that painter "i" paints only boards which are left to the boards painted by painter "j" if i is smaller than j. This can be easily solved using DP,but how to approach the original problem using DP ?

Thank You..

Answer (score 4):

I just came across this problem myself and I think it's really neat.

The DP solution is to consider a grid where one degree of freedom is the number of painters (from 1->k) and the other is the index of the list of boards (so as you traverse this degree of freedom you are adding one more board in each time).

The first thing to observe is that if you have one painter then the time taken to paint up to board A[i] is the sum of the size of those boards up to that point. Conversely, if you just have the first board, and you keep adding painters, the time taken is simply the size of that board, more painters doesn't help.

Now the trick is to think about how to use this information to calculate the optimal time for 2 painters and 2 boards. Let's draw up the first part of the table explicitly

```
     | k = 1 | k = 2 | k = 3 |
------------------------------
| b1 |  S_00 |  S_00 |  S_00 |
| b2 |  S_01 |       |       |
| b3 |  S_02 |       |       |
```

The column index is 'k' the number of painters and the row index is how many boards you are including (in order). S_ij is the sum of the costs for one painter to paint boards i to j (so S_00 = A[0] )

So for 2 painters and 2 boards, one painter painting both is S_01, and one painting each is max(A[0] ,A[1]) because the time will be determined by whichever board is larger.

So the best we can do with 2 painters and 2 boards is the minimum of these two, so the new entry in the table will be

```
min(S_01, max(A[0],A[1])
```

You can then continue filling the table according to the same logic.

However, what is really cool is you can do this in logarithmic time using a binary search! I have also assumed here all the painters paint at the same rate otherwise it is waaaay harder.

Comment: Your elaboration is igniting and inspirational.
Could you continue to explain how to get final Dynamic Programming solution formula ?
Also when you have some time later, may you elaborate binary search solution too.

Thanks 10k, - Charlie